# Publishing mathematics content in a blog

Tags: soft-question

I would like just to publish few math-related blog entries on blog.com. For drawing and animation, I can use pictures (for animation, they would be animated gifs). However, what to do with equation, and similar content?

Note that blog editors offer only basic html editing.

Comment: Inline images? italics, subscripts, superscipts for the most basic stuff?

Comment: Subscripts and superscripts would not be the problem in that blog editor, however I need more than this.

Comment: Use MathJaX http://www.mathjax.com/ it is the same that this site uses to display math. You need to know LaTeX code however but any serious typesetting of mathematics ought to involve LaTeX.

Comment: @SergioParreiras For personal blogs, [KaTeX is much faster than MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27217242/3184351).  @ VividD To set up a personal math blog, [my meta answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29462/290189) might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people use $\LaTeX$ for math-related typesetting.

you may want to look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19928/how-can-i-use-latex-to-build-my-website

Comment: Yes, many thanks, it looks this Pandoc tool could be useful for me. However, I am not sure, if the blog site would accept html output of Pandoc - since they don't allow full standard html (if they had allowed, I wouldnt have had this problem), just a subset, but I will try Pandoc.

Answer (score 2):

Use either Wikipedia or some math-related site such as this to temporarily create LaTeX content, use print screen, and then upload the picture onto your blog.

Comment: Depending on client settings, Wikipedia will even create ready-to-use PNG files for you (no need to crop them from a printscreen)

Comment: That's what I was considering too. It solves the problem, but its a kind of hard to manage...

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if those images require licensing information or the like. (Understandibly, the Wikipedia squirrels won't be happy about people using the site as a free TeX-to-PNG tool)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Have you ever asked them ? They allow user pages and sub-pages, and I personally have a few little math pages hosted there.

Comment: @Lucian They (actually: we) specifically say [what Wikipedia is not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:What_Wikipedia_is_not), and hosting pages vie user pages is listed there.